# where to get typings for ethereum object on window

Tags: typescript

I was wondering where to get typings for the ethereum object on window that would be added through the metamask or some other wallet extension. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ethers has a definition for this called [`ExternalProvider`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/73a46efea32c3f9a4833ed77896a216e3d3752a0/packages/providers/src.ts/web3-provider.ts#L13). The interface is defined in [EIP-1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193).

You can also find a good answer for this on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504958/web3-js-extending-the-window-interface-type-definitions

Answer (score 1):

I will just dump what I use currently here.

###### `src/{anything}.ts` e.g. `src/interfaces.d.ts`

```
interface Window {
  // pick one
  ethereum: EthereumProvider
  // ethereum: ExternalProvider
  // ethereum: AbstractProvider
}

// ExternalProvider seems to be the official ethersproject type for the window.ethereum object, however, `new Web3(ethereum)` does not like it so we must improvise.
declare type ExternalProvider = import('@ethersproject/providers').ExternalProvider
declare type AbstractProvider = import('web3/node_modules/web3-core/types').AbstractProvider
interface EthereumProvider extends ExternalProvider {
  _state: any
  sendAsync: AbstractProvider['sendAsync']
}
```

This file is a script as it does not import and export anything (unlike module), making its declarations ambient - available globally. Just make sure it is included in the `tsconfig.json` file in the include/blob array `"include": ["..."]`.

More reading:
https://github.com/MetaMask/providers
[github.com~ethers.js @ ExternalProvider](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/73a46efea32c3f9a4833ed77896a216e3d3752a0/packages/providers/src.ts/web3-provider.ts#L13)